# React Onmouseover Suggestion

Tags: css, reactjs, onmouseover

I'm learning build website using react and bootstrap css,
i have carousel, and separated navigation.
below example code of my carousel

```
class Home extends React.Component {
     mousehover() {
         ... ???? .....
     };
     render() { return (
        <div className="row">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" className="carousel slide col-9" data-ride="carousel">
                <div className="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div className="carousel-item active">
                        <img className="d-block img-fluid" src="http://northdelawhere.happeningmag.com/wp-content/uploads/banner_sample300x300.jpg"
                            alt="First slide" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="carousel-item">
                        <img className="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.raymiller.cc/thumbnail/exterior-beadboard-paneling-4-texture-plus-indoor-outdoor-siding-panel-beadboard-oak-sample-300-x-300.jpg"
                            alt="Second slide" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="carousel-item">
                        <img className="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="Third slide" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a className="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a className="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className="col-3">
                <ul className="flex-column">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" onmouseover={this.mousehover}>one</li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1">two</li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2">three</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
    )} 
}
React.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

i'm trying create event for my list using onmousehover, but failed.
anyone can help me for give clue / example for onmousehover event which will slide to target carousel (data-slide-to) ?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`SyntheticEvent` section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events) of the React docs, it explains how to use events like `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` in React:

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of `SyntheticEvent`, a
>   cross-browser wrapper around the browser's native event. It has the
>   same interface as the browser's native event, including
>   `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`, except the events work
>   identically across all browsers.

---

That said, depending on your use case, you be better off implementing the hover effect using CSS's `:hover` pseudo-class.